# xvfb-run on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, xvfb

I'm trying to run [SlimerJS](https://slimerjs.org/index.html) in headless mode so that it does not open a visible browser window on Mac OSX.

According to [the SlimerJS docs](http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/installation.html#having-a-headless-slimerjs), this can be done using `xvfb` which is *"available on Linux and MacOS"*, using the command:

```
>> xvfb-run ./slimerjs myscript.js.
```

Although OSX comes with bundled with `xvfb`, it does not have the corresponding `xvfb-run` script.

How can I get the same functionality using the OSX `xvfb` version?

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like the following (works for me with running my python test cases):

```
$ Xvfb :1337 & export DISPLAY=:1337 & ./slimerjs myscript.js.
```

Comment: Will be good if you can provide some explanation of what this command will do.

Comment: Not an `xvfb` expert, but `Xvfb :1337` starts an "*x*-window *v*irtual *f*rame *b*uffer" (xvfb), which will pretend to be a window server, but will not write anything to a screen) listening on port 1337; `export DISPLAY=:1337` sets the `DISPLAY` env variable to that same port number - so X applications send their screen commands to that port; `./slimerjs mysript.js` calls the application, which will believe to be writing on the screen, running headless as we want.

Comment: (it could be any port, but @mweppler seems to be a [leet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) person :-) )

Comment: I think xvfb-run also kills the Xvfb process after running the process, maybe a killall xvfb at the end would be helpful ?